# Factor property of modulo?

Tags: number-theory

Can I find the result of $a\mod n \equiv b$, only knowing the result from prime factors of $n$.

> **Example:**
>
> Let $n = 6$, $a=10$ so $b = 4$, but can this be found only knowing $a\mod 2 \equiv 0$ and $a\mod 3 \equiv 1$, where $2$ and $3$ are the prime factors of the number $6$ ($n$ in this case).

Comment: Do you know that $n$ is square free?  If so, then the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) gets the job done.  If not, then you can't...both $5,7$ are odd but one is $1 \pmod 4$ and the other is $3\mod 4$.  for non-square free $n$ you need to know the remainders modulo prime power divisors.

Comment: Please use formatting tools: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @lulu what do you mean by n being square free.

Comment: $a\pmod 3\equiv 1$, surely?

Comment: "square free" means that $n$ is not divisible by $p^2$ for any prime $p$.  $6$ is square free.  $4=2^2$ is not.